# How to test a Rails app which has bower's dependencies to a private git repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ssh, bower, wercker

I am working on testing my Rails app which has bower-rails gem on wercker.com.

The wercker.yml has the following setting.

```
- script:
    name: rake bower:install
    code: bundle exec rake bower:install
```

And the bower.json on the app has some dependencies which have my private git repository.

So, during the test an error occurs because the wercker couldn't access to the private repository. The error was like below.

```
bower foo#*                                 ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git@bitbucket.org:myrepository/foo.git", exit code of #128 Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts. Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Additional error details:
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
rake aborted!
```

Any solutions?

Comment: i think you're looking for this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=302811860